# What is wrong with my div layout?

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to get my footer div to go to the bottom. It is always at the bottom of my container div but my container div is always height:0. I tried setting overflow to hidden in the container div but the height was still 0 and it made all my other divs dissapear. What is wrong? Here is my css and html.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head></head>

    <body background="images/bg.png">
        <div id="contentcontainer">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/banner.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
            </div>
            <div id="form">
                <!--This is where the form goes-->
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <!--This is where the content goes-->
            </div>

            <div id="submission"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                <p id="footertext">Copyright © 2013 me.com. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
 #submission {
    width:500px;
    height:175px;
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    top:225px;
}
#header {
    width: 820px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#nav {
    width: 820px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 150px;
}
#form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 820px;
    height: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #666666;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
}
#content {
    border: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 820px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 376px;
    min-height: 1200px;
    height: auto;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #666666;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#footertext {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
#contentcontainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 820px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Because the footer is inside your container div. Put it at the end of your body and see if that works. Sidenote: You should probably use names like content_container/footer_text or content-container/footer-text or contentContainer/footerText. It improves readability

Comment: That just puts it at the bottom of the screen. I want it to move with the scaling size of the content. and be at the bottom of my container. Thx for response though.

Comment: Do you want your footer to be sticky at the bottom?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?(giving a `min-height` to your `#contentcontainer` might do the trick)

Comment: The `contentcontainer` height is always zero because all its children elements are `absolute`-positioned. If you know the heights of all the children elements & their positions before hand then do some calculations and set the height of the `contentcontainer` as well to some fixed value like `990px`.

Comment: Your Css is looking very dangerous. As possible avoid using absolute, in this responsive world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of your container div is zero because all of the children are positioned as absolute. If you could achieve the same without absolute positioning, you'll notice that the container div actually takes some space.

Its not a good idea to make everything absolutely positioned.